# C++ mfc create a mail sending button?

Tags: c++, mfc

is it possible to create a button in C++ MFS dialog based document so that after pressing that it sends some data to your email?

Comment: You are looking for "send email with c++". The way it will be invoked doesn't matter (the fact that you want to use button within MFC dialog is irrelevant).

Comment: Please be more specific. What should the button do exactly ? Send an email to a specific address ? Open your email program with a ready to send message ? Or... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions that come with the MAPI ActiveX control, to send an email. I had done this in Visual C++ 6.

Edit :

The ActiveX control does not show up in the toolbox on Visual Studio 2010 , so you have add them.

[image]

You need to add both the controls. After adding the controls, create a variable for the controls and the respective classes shall be generated .

Mapi Session to keep track of the session - Logon / Logoff

Mapi Messages to compose the message and send them.